# GNU make is adding an extra step not in my Makefile that causes all sorts of linker errors. What's going on?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given the following makefile for GNU make:

```
# TODOs so I don't forget:
# - make debugging an option
# - make 64 below an actual option
# - figure out why make test seems to rebuild the DLL
# - __declspec(dllimport)

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),64)
    CC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
    RC = x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres
    mflag = -m64
else
    CC = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
    RC = i686-w64-mingw32-windres
    mflag = -m32
endif

OBJDIR = .objs
OUTDIR = out

BASENAME = wintable
DLLFILE = $(OUTDIR)/$(BASENAME).dll
LIBFILE = $(OUTDIR)/$(BASENAME).lib
TESTEXEFILE = $(OUTDIR)/$(BASENAME).exe

CFILES = \
    alloc.c \
    api.c \
    checkboxdraw.c \
    checkboxevents.c \
    children.c \
    coord.c \
    debug.c \
    draw.c \
    events.c \
    header.c \
    hscroll.c \
    main.c \
    metrics.c \
    modelhelpers.c \
    nullmodel.c \
    resize.c \
    scroll.c \
    select.c \
    update.c \
    util.c \
    visibility.c \
    vscroll.c

HFILES = \
    table.h \
    tablepriv.h

TESTCFILES = \
    test.c

OFILES = $(CFILES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
TESTOFILES = $(TESTCFILES:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

xCFLAGS = \
    --std=c99 \
    -Wall \
    -Wextra \
    -Wno-unused-parameter \
    $(mflag) \
    $(CFLAGS)

xLDFLAGS = \
    -static-libgcc \
    -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -luxtheme -lole32 -loleaut32 -loleacc -luuid -lmsimg32 \
    $(mflag) \
    $(LDFLAGS)

default:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) it
    $(MAKE) test

it: $(DLLFILE)

$(DLLFILE): $(OFILES)
    $(CC) -g -o $(DLLFILE) -shared -Wl,--out-implib,$(LIBFILE) $(OFILES) $(xLDFLAGS)

test: $(TESTEXEFILE)

$(TESTEXEFILE): $(DLLFILE) $(TESTOFILES)
    $(CC) -g -o $(TESTEXEFILE) $(TESTOFILES) $(LIBFILE) $(xLDFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(HFILES) dirs
    $(CC) -g -o $@ -c $< $(xCFLAGS)

dirs:
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR) $(OUTDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(OUTDIR)
```

`make -n test` produces

```
mkdir -p .objs out
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o .objs/alloc.o -c alloc.c --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m32 
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o .objs/api.o -c api.c --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m32 
(and so on for all the other C files)
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o out/wintable.dll -shared -Wl,--out-implib,out/wintable.lib .objs/alloc.o .objs/api.o .objs/checkboxdraw.o .objs/checkboxevents.o .objs/children.o .objs/coord.o .objs/debug.o .objs/draw.o .objs/events.o .objs/header.o .objs/hscroll.o .objs/main.o .objs/metrics.o .objs/modelhelpers.o .objs/nullmodel.o .objs/resize.o .objs/scroll.o .objs/select.o .objs/update.o .objs/util.o .objs/visibility.o .objs/vscroll.o -static-libgcc -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -luxtheme -lole32 -loleaut32 -loleacc -luuid -lmsimg32 -m32 
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o .objs/test.o -c test.c --std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m32 
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o out/wintable.exe .objs/test.o out/wintable.lib -static-libgcc -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -luxtheme -lole32 -loleaut32 -loleacc -luuid -lmsimg32 -m32 
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc     test.c out/wintable.exe   -o test
```

Notice how the last step that GNU make decides to do tries to recompile my test.c with the correct output executable file built before that into a new `test` executable, which (predictably) fails spectacularly:

```
out/wintable.exe: In function `WinMainCRTStartup':
/build/buildd/mingw-w64-3.1.0/build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/../../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:171: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:/build/buildd/mingw-w64-3.1.0/build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/../../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:171: first defined here
out/wintable.exe: In function `mainCRTStartup':
/build/buildd/mingw-w64-3.1.0/build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/../../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:199: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o:/build/buildd/mingw-w64-3.1.0/build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/../../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:199: first defined here
out/wintable.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x500): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
out/wintable.exe:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x550): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x50): first defined here
out/wintable.exe: In function `mainwinCreate':
/home/pietro/src/github.com/andlabs/wintable/test.c:20: multiple definition of `mainwinCreate'
/tmp/cc50VrIz.o:test.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
out/wintable.exe: In function `mainwinDestroy':
/home/pietro/src/github.com/andlabs/wintable/test.c:66: multiple definition of `mainwinDestroy'
/tmp/cc50VrIz.o:test.c:(.text+0x2ba): first defined here
(and so on for virtually every symbol in my test.c)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbegin.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Where is this last step coming from? It's nowhere in my makefile, as far as I can tell. (Notice the lack of compiler flags.) Googling the problem was also ineffective here. This only started to happen today, with all the same rules as before (the only change is the addition of `modelhelpers.c` and `nullmodel.c` to `CFILES`), so I'm not sure what's going on.

Does it have to do with the rule being `test`? If so, why did it work before?

This is GNU make 4.0 on Ubuntu GNOME 14.10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make has various built-in implicit rules, and one of them is the pattern rule `% : %.c`, which tells make how to create an executable (in UNIX systems, executables don't have any extension like `.exe` etc., they're just words like `test`, `mkdir`, etc.) if it has a source file with the same extension.

Your makefile has:

```
test: $(TESTEXEFILE)
```

and you provide no recipe for building the target `test`, so make looks at its built-in rules and finds `% : %.c`, and then make looks and sees that you *DO* have a `test.c` file, so make applies that default recipe to build the target `test`, which you asked it to do.

If you don't want this to happen you should tell make that `test` is not a real target: that you're only using it as a handle to build other things, using the [`.PHONY` special target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

```
.PHONY: test
```

From the manual:

> The implicit rule search is skipped for .PHONY targets.

Comment: Ah, that was it; thanks. I was suspecting it was some default behavior but I didn't think the lack of a recipe would cause it to fall back :/ Oh well. I'm surprised there's the `% : %.c` rule to begin with; what's the idea behind that? If it's to allow building programs quickly with just `make program`, wouldn't you need a makefile anyway? (`%.o : %.c` would make more sense to me :/ )

Comment: No.  The point of built-in rules is you do _not_ need a makefile; they are built-in! :).  So, in an appropriate situation you could build simple things with no makefile.  However, I generally agree that there are quite a few built-in rules which are pretty useless these days, and often cause more problems than solutions.  Nevertheless, for backward-compatibility (and in some cases, compatibility with the POSIX standard) it's hard to remove them.

Comment: In this case, for example, POSIX requires this built-in rule to exist (although they express it in terms of suffix files, because POSIX doesn't have pattern rules).

Comment: All right then! (By "need a makefile" I meant "a file `Makefile` in the current directory" or "the above, and it just has `all: programName`" but I guess the answer is the same in those cases.) Thanks again!

Comment: (oh and of course, `make` absolutely _does_ have a built-in rule for `%.o : %.c`, but that doesn't apply here because you're building `$(OBJDIR)/test.o`, not `test.o`).

Comment: Yes; no file named `Makefile` is needed in the current directory to use the built-in rules; that's what I'm saying.  If you  have a directory with no files in it at all except `test.c` and you run `make test`, make will (try to) compile and link `test.c` into the program `test`.